# Semantic error - property not found on object of type

Tags: ios, objective-c, semantics

I am receiving a semantic error "property 'tableView' not found on object of type 'XYZAddToDoItemViewController *'. Here is the code for ToDoListViewController.m where I receive the error:

```
- (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
XYZAddToDoItemViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController];
XYZToDoItem *item = source.toDoItem;
if (item != nil) {
    [self.toDoItems addObject:item];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
}
```

Here is the top of the implementation file:

```
#import "XYZToDoItem.h"

#import "XYZAddToDoItemViewController.h"

@interface XYZAddToDoItemViewController ()

@property NSMutableArray *toDoItems;

@end

@implementation XYZAddToDoItemViewController
```

Here is XYZAddToDoItemViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "XYZToDoItem.h"

@interface XYZAddToDoItemViewController : UIViewController
@property XYZToDoItem *toDoItem;
@end
```

Please let me know if you need any more information, and thanks in advance for any help you may offer!

Comment: I don't see "`tableView`" anywhere in the code you've cut and pasted into this question.  Where is "`tableView`" property declared?

Comment: I never declared property "tableView", my understanding was that it was an inherited property. The implementation file makes use of the tableView elsewhere without error, for instance here: - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

Comment: @user2651272 If you think its an inherited property then you should be subclassing UITablViewController not UIViewController. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.htmle

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. UIViewController does not have or inherit a tableView property. If you implement the table view data source methods, a tableView argument is passed in by the table view, which is why those methods work without error.

Comment: Thank you for the correction rdelmar, that is starting to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you need is a UITableViewController where you have the property **self.tableView**.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried this before and when doing so I receive Apple Mach-O Linker Error: 'Link command failed with exit code 1'

Comment: ok what is the linker error? Are you using storyboards if so you got to make changes there too.

Comment: I believe it is 3 duplicate symbol errors (duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_XYZAddToDoItemViewController._toDoItem in:). Yes I am using a storyboard, I have the view controllers custom class properly set, other than that I'm not sure what else to double check on a storyboard.

Comment: The property toDoItem has been declared more than once, why are you doing #import "XYZToDoItem.h" both in .h and .m, doing that once is enuf but I don't think that will solve our problem here. Check whether you have declared the same property elsewhere in your project and you have imported that class in here.

Comment: I was following instructions on page 105 under "Add New Items": https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/RoadMapiOS.pdf

Comment: - (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue function is in which class?? ToDoListViewController.m right??

Comment: ToDoListViewController is a subclass of UITablViewController ??

Comment: Just to make sure I remade the ToDoListViewController and subclassed it from UITableViewController. Still receiving the linker error